# How can I extend Jade templates that are not stored on disk?

Tags: pug, extends

I am writing a small CMS application using NodeJS and Jade. For various reasons I want to store my Jade template files in a database (e.g. MongoDB), not on disk.

This works fine for a simple, self-contained Jade template: I can simply fetch the Jade string from the database, and `jade.compile` it.

However, if the template `extends` another template, I seem to be forced into storing my templates on disk. From `jade.js`:

```
  parseExtends: function(){
    var fs = _dereq_('fs');

    var path = this.resolvePath(this.expect('extends').val.trim(), 'extends');
    if ('.jade' != path.substr(-5)) path += '.jade';

    var str = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    ...
```

So the `extends` keyword explicitly assumes the extended template is stored on disk.

What is the easiest way to let my Jade templates extend other templates that are stored in a database - or any other repository?

Comment: I would intent to fork the Jade project from github and implements the functionality, or else you can pull a request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this can be accomplished [by overriding `parseExtends` and `parseImports`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1615#issuecomment-51053864).

However, you will need some kind of synchronous storage, as Jade does all compilation synchronously. That is, no callbacks.

I eventually "solved" this by prefetching *all* templates and storing them in a `templateMap` object:

```
{
  "path": "/templates/frontpage.jade",
  "content": "<html><body>Here's some Jade</body></html>"
},
...
```

Then overriding `parseExtends` and `parseImports` so that they look for the template path in `templateMap`, not on disk:

```
jade.Parser.prototype.parseExtends = function () {
    var path = this.expect('extends').val.trim();
    path = Path.normalize(path).replace("\\", "/"); // Necessary on Windows
    var self = this;
    var str = templatesMap[path];
    if (!str) {
        return callback(new RendererError("Could not find template " + path));
    }
    var parser = new this.constructor(str, path, this.options);

    parser.blocks = this.blocks;
    parser.contexts = this.contexts;
    self.extending = parser;
    return new Nodes.Literal('');
}
```